# How do i force angular filter to refresh the order by after adding to array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use an array of items to populate a table for display. I can add items to this array and they are displayed automatically and sort correctly when loaded initially with the code below.

```
<tr ng-repeat="eachData in eventData | orderBy: 'StartDateTime'">
  ...                  
</tr>
```

When I add a new item it is not sorted by the StartDateTime, but saved at the bottom of the list. When I save save and refresh the page the items will be ordered correctly. When I edit the items StartDateTime and do a $scope.$apply() the edited item is ordered correctly. The $scope.$apply() does not seem to help me with the new item added to the array. Any suggestions?

Comment: StartDateTime is a date, please check datatype of StartDateTime for new item you want to add

Comment: That was it, good call. Write it up so i can give you credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StartDateTime is a date, please check datatype of StartDateTime for new item you want to add

```
eventData.push({StartDateTime: new Date()})
```

hope this help